# CreateDIBSection to get uint8_t[] of portion of screen

Tags: winapi, screenshot

I am trying to get a uint8_t[] of a portion of the screen. The xy coordinates of the top left is 2,3 and of bottom right is 17,18.

This is the top 30x30 pixels of my screen with regular screenshot and photoshop crop:

[image]

And this is what 2,3 to 17,18 screenshot should look like via regular screenshot and Photoshop crop:

[image]

This is what I am getting as a result of my code:

[image]

My code is in js-ctypes but there is no ctypes errors. This is a winapi thing. So I didn't tag this with ctypes as they would be confused. This is the simplified code I am using, the error checks etc have been removed:

```
c1 = {x:2, y:3} // top left corner
c2 = {x:17, y:18} // bottom right corner

CreateDC('DISPLAY', null, null, null);
nBPP = GetDeviceCaps(hdcScreen, BITSPIXEL);

w = c2.x - c1.x; // width = 15
h = c2.y - c1.y; // height = 15

hdcMemoryDC = CreateCompatibleDC(hdcScreen);

bmi = BITMAPINFO();
bmi.bmiHeader.biSize = BITMAPINFOHEADER.size;
bmi.bmiHeader.biWidth = w;
bmi.bmiHeader.biHeight = -1 * h;
bmiHeader.biPlanes = 1;
bmi.bmiHeader.biBitCount = nBPP; // nBPP is 32
bmi.bmiHeader.biCompression = BI_RGB;

hbmp = CreateDIBSection(hdcScreen, &bmi, DIB_RGB_COLORS, (void**)&pixelBuffer, null, 0);

SelectObject(hdcMemoryDC, hbmp);
BitBlt(hdcMemoryDC, 0, 0, w, h, hdcScreen, c1.x, c1.y, SRCCOPY);
```

Why portion of screen bits come out wrong? If I do a full screen shot it works fine.

Comment: How do you draw the image? When I BitBlt the contents of `hdcMemoryDC` to the HDC of a window the displayed image is correct.

Comment: Thanks very much @LukasThomsen for that test, I am putting the byte array into ImageData.data then drawing that to HTML5 canvas element. So maybe this isn't a C issue then, thanks much for your test.

Comment: Try `hbmp = CreateCompatibleBitmap(hdcScreen, w, h)` instead of `CreateDIBSection` if possible.

Comment: Are you certain nBPP is 32 and not 24 (or 16)?  If it's not 32, then your scanlines won't be DWORD aligned, which seems consistent with the illustrated problem.  (24 bits per pixel is 3 bytes, and the width is 15 bytes, so the stride would be 45 bytes which is not a multiple of 4.)

Comment: @AdrianMcCarthy you are correct, it has to be 32. I actually got it via `DEVMODE.dmBitsPerPel` from `EnumDisplaySettings` to be sure.